# How to customize owl carousel slider

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, owl-carousel

I've added the owl carousel 2 (the most recent update) to my theme.  I've added the carousel successfully.  However, I have no control over customizing it.  I've tried editing the owl-carousel.js file and I've tried editing my owl.carousel-init.js file, but neither of them give me the customizations I want.  The main one being that I only want 5 owl items and there are currently 8.  Have I added all of the correct files?  This is the first theme I'm building, so I'm not 100% confident I did everything right. Can someone help spot the error I made, and help me customize it? Thanks in advance.

I set up my carousel.php file to show the most recent popular posts*

front-page.php

```html
<?php 
/* 
* Template Name: 
*/ 

get_header(); 
get_template_part ('inc/carousel'); 

$the_query = new WP_Query( [ 
'posts_per_page' => 14, 
'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1) 
] ); 

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?> 
<div id="ajax"> 
<?php 
$i = 0; 
$j = 0; 
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post(); 

if ( $i % 7 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?> 
<div class="row"> 
<article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-12 col-md-12' ); ?>> 
<div class="large-front-container"> 
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?> 
</div> 
<h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
<p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
<div class="front-page-post-info"> 
<a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a> 
<?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?> 
<?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?> 
<div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div> 
</div> 
</article> 
</div> 

<?php 

} else { // Small posts ?> 
<?php if($j % 3 === 0) echo '<div class="row">'; ?> 
<article <?php post_class( 'col-md-4' ); ?>> 
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?> 
<h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
<p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
<div class="front-page-post-info"> 
<a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a> 
<?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?> 
<?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?> 
<div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div> 
</div> 
</article> 

<?php $j++; if($j % 3 === 0) echo '</div>'; ?> 
<?php 
} 
$i++; 
}?> 

</div> 
<?php if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) { 
load_more_button(); 
} 
} 
elseif (!get_query_var('paged') || get_query_var('paged') == '1') { 
echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>'; 
} 
wp_reset_postdata(); 
get_footer();
```

carousel.php

```html
<div class="owl-carousel"> 
<?php 
$carousel_cat = get_theme_mod('carousel_setting','1'); 
$carousel_count = get_theme_mod('count_setting','4'); 
$month = date('m'); 
$year = date('Y'); 
$new_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => $carousel_count, 'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC','monthnum'=>$month,'year'=>$year )); 
?> 
<?php if ( $new_query->have_posts() ) : ?> 
<?php while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) : $new_query->the_post(); ?> 
<div class="item"> 
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('popular-posts'); ?>
    <h2><a class="popular-category" 
        <?php 
        $categories = get_the_category(); 
        $separator = ", ";
        $output = '';
        
        if ($categories) {
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                $output .= '<a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->cat_name . '</a>' . $separator;
            }
            echo trim($output, $separator);
        }
        
        ?></a></h2>
 <p>
     <a class="popular-excerpt" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></a>
                </p>
</div> 
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?> 
<?php else : ?> 
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, No Popular Posts Found ' ); ?></p> 
<?php endif; ?> 
</div>
```

owl.carousel-init.js

```html
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({

      autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds

      items : 4,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]

  });

});
```

functions.php

```html
unction templatename_add_owlcarousel() {
wp_enqueue_script ( 'jquery' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'owl-carousel-init', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/owl.carousel-init.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'owl-carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/owl.carousel.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
wp_enqueue_style( 'owlcarousel-style-theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.theme.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'owlcarousel-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.carousel.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'templatename_add_owlcarousel' );
```

footer.php

```html
script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/owl.carousel-init.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/owl.carousel.js"></script> 
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

FILES IV'E ADDED

css/owl.carousel.css

css/owl.theme.css

js/owl.carousel.js

Answer (score 1):

owl.carousel-init.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
    responsive:{
      0:{
      items:1,
      nav:true
      },
      600:{
      items:2,
      nav:false
      },
      1000:{
      items:4,
      nav:true,
      loop:false
      }
    }
  });
});
```

and in footer.php

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/owl.carousel.js"></script> 
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/owl.carousel-init.js"></script>
```

hope this helps..